# Use WikipediaData offline

Tags: wikipedia

I am a Mathematica beginner. I wonder if the `WikipediaData` feature (new in version 10, i think) can be used off-line, I mean, to use it with a local download of Wikipedia.

Just to be more precise:

I have 25 files of the form **wikipedia_en_all_2015-05.zima{i}**, where **i** represents the alphabet letters from **a** to **z**. That's a typical Wikipedia download. What I wan is to import articles from this databases to Mathematica, in the same fashion that can be done with `WikipediaData`

Comment: No. WikipediaData is basically an easy to use interface for the Wikipedia API.

Comment: If you want to do really heavy stuff, you have to download one of the offline repositories and work with that directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I am afraid I don't understand very well your last comment. Could you explain me a little verbose?

Comment: I haven't really done this myself, so I don't know exactly how to do it. There are compressed collections of the most popular wikipedia pages available to download for wikipedia. You can download these and use them. They ask people to do this if they're going to be heavily using their API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the OP is asking for a capability that does not exist in the version of _Mathematica_ the OP is using.

Comment: That's the whole point! I am asking if it exits! So if you know for sure it doesn't please tell me.

Comment: No, WikipediaData needs an internet connection. What @Searke I think was to download a dump from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ and install it in your machine. You will need to install first MediaWiki (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download)